# MySQL order results by date after a group by

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

We are working on a project for school and have a small issue with a query.
What we try to do is the following:

Select the `education-unit(s)` with the same `version_vid` and after that select the `education-unit` with the latest `version_date`.
But whatever we try, the `education-unit` with the lowest `euid` is returning.

We are using the Yii2 framework for this project, the ActiveQuery we use is:

```
EducationUnit::find()->groupBy('version_vid')->orderBy('version_date DESC');
```

SQL Fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9929d/2/0

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure about Yii but is it what you are looking at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9929d/26 ?

Comment: Fiddle's are great. Kind of meaningless without a desired result, donchathink?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you:

```
EducationUnit::find()
    ->from('select * from education_unit ORDER BY version_date DESC')
    ->groupBy('version_vid')
    ->all();
```

Comment: It works if I give the subquery an alias like this:

`EducationUnit::find()->from('(SELECT * FROM education_unit ORDER BY version_date DESC) a')->groupBy('a.version_vid')`

But this is the same solution as @Daan I think? Only in a Yii2 way.

Answer (score -1):

Wrap a select around your query, after that do the group by:

```
SELECT * FROM
( SELECT * FROM `education_unit` ORDER BY `version_date` DESC ) a
GROUP BY a.`version_vid`
```

Why it didn't work in your query is because SQL has an execution plan as below:

- FROM clause
- WHERE clause
- GROUP BY clause
- HAVING clause
- SELECT clause
- ORDER BY clause

Comment: While that probably will work.. it is not guaranteed to. The non-aggregate columns are assigned arbitrary values from the group, not necessarily the first one that is hit. I would avoid this solution.

Answer (score -1):

The reason you are getting the lowest`euid` is that the `ORDER BY` is applied after the `GROUP BY` and the `GROUP BY` is choosing arbitrary values from the group to return.

This is a classic top in group question and has been [answered previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/fetch-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-for-a-column/123481#123481)

I personally like the answer supplied by Bill Karwin which when applied to your situation becomes:

```
   SELECT t.*
     FROM table t
LEFT JOIN table t2
       ON t2.version_vid = t.version_vid 
      AND t2.version_date > t.version_date
    WHERE t2.version_vid IS NULL
```

Another common solution is:

```
   SELECT t.*
     FROM table t
     JOIN (
       SELECT version_id, MAX(version_date) version_date
         FROM table
     GROUP BY version_id
          ) t2
       ON t2.version_id   = t1.version_id
      AND t2.version_date = t1.version_date
```

Comment: That link is rather dated. The top answer works, but is orders of magnitude slower that a non-correlated subquery. (I didn't dv btw)